# How to structure the security of child objects when a user only has access to the parent

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a database structure something similar to the following:

```
User
----
Id
Name

UserCustomerLink
----------------
UserId
CustomerId

Customer
--------
Id
Name

Address
-------
Id
CustomerId
Address1

Invoice
-------
Id
AddressId
Number
```

This a asp.net mvc site so a user can go to an address like `http://localhost/invoice/details/1` which will return the invoice with an id of 1.

A user needs to be logged in and be assigned to the customer (via the UserCustomerLink table) that the invoice (via the address) belongs to.

My question is where should I be doing the check that the user can view the invoice?

Should I check the invoice exists and the user can view it and then return it from the database or should I retrieve the item from the database and then check?

I'm concerned about the number of database queries that will be executed to find this information and I'm looking for an efficient method. This a simplistic view of the structure and some of the child properties go more than 3 deep.

On a site note I'm using Entity Framework code first so if there's a way to create a mapping that includes the Customer Id in the Invoice object this could potential get around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to make two trips to the database.  You can use joins and do one select.  All your tables have foreign keys that link the records.  When the query returns you check that the User is linked to that invoice.  You could do this same thing with LINQ

```
SELECT 
    i.*,
    c.Name
FROM 
    INVOICE i JOIN 
    Address a JOIN
        on i.addressId = a.id
    Customer c JOIN
        on a.customerID = c.id
    UserCustomerLink ucl join
        on c.id = ucl.CustomerId
    User u
        on ucl.Userid = User.id
WHERE 
    i.Id = @invoiceId
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, just wondered if there was a "neater" way that didnt require as many joins, but seems to run quick enough.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Authorize attribute.  You could put your users into Roles and then let the framework check for you.

```
[Authorize(Roles="AllowedUser")]
public ViewResult GetInvoies()
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: What you describe is roles based security which this is not. As the user can have access to more than one object it is not a matter of roles but access rights which vary between every user.